# Can I install Yosemite and work on iOS 7 with Xcode 5?

Tags: osx-yosemite

I want to use the latest OS X on my Mac Pro and work with iOS 7. Will I have any problems if I update my Mac Pro to Yosemite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that won't be a problem and you can even use Xcode 6 with the iOS 8 SDK and simply make the deployment target iOS 7.

However if this is your only machine you are in danger of breaking your only programming resource; better is to install Yosemite on a spare partition and leave Mavericks in place until Yosemite is more stable.  You can then dual-boot as required.

Comment: @WYS OK, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: @WYS Ah, it is relevant as that's what the OP actually asked :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to install Xcode 5 on OSX Yosemite via the app store "because the version of OS X is too new". I'm not sure what happens if it was already installed when you upgraded though.

[image: Xcode can't be installed]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can burn OS X Yosemite to a USB Flash Drive, here is a good example:
[How to Burn OS X Yosemite to a USB Flash Drive](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-burn-os-x-yosemite-to-a-usb-flash-drive-1647137212)